# Format JSON data using tidyjson

Tags: json, r

I would love to use the tidyjson package as it seems to have very clear instructions on how to use it.

However, I am having a few issues. Could you please help check and let me know if these are user issues or something else.

1. I am using the world_bank.json data downloaded from http://jsonstudio.com/resources/

   worldbank <- fromJSON(file = "world_bank.json")

I do see that a list of 50 in Rstudio. However, when I try to use read_json, I get the below error.

```
> read_json(worldbank, format = "json")
Error in file.info(path) : invalid filename argument


> worldbank[[1]] %>% prettify
Error: parse error: trailing garbage
                                     52b213b38594d8a2be17c780
                     (right here) ------^
```

Comment: I would try to use `jsonlite`package : `json_file <- stream_in(file("world_bank.json"))`

Comment: @lizzie. Thanks. I am now able to read in the data. But how come #1 fails, but #2 is able to prettify the data 
#1. json_file[[1]] %>% prettify; #2. worldbank[[1]] %>% prettify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jsonlite::stream_in` as lizzy suggested with stream unzip:

```
> download.file("http://jsonstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/world_bank.zip", "world_bank.zip")
> world_bank <- jsonlite::stream_in(unz("world_bank.zip", "world_bank.json"))
> names(world_bank)
 [1] "_id"                      "approvalfy"               "board_approval_month"    
 [4] "boardapprovaldate"        "borrower"                 "closingdate"             
 [7] "country_namecode"         "countrycode"              "countryname"             
[10] "countryshortname"         "docty"                    "envassesmentcategorycode"
[13] "grantamt"                 "ibrdcommamt"              "id"                      
[16] "idacommamt"               "impagency"                "lendinginstr"            
[19] "lendinginstrtype"         "lendprojectcost"          "majorsector_percent"     
[22] "mjsector_namecode"        "mjtheme"                  "mjtheme_namecode"        
[25] "mjthemecode"              "prodline"                 "prodlinetext"            
[28] "productlinetype"          "project_abstract"         "project_name"            
[31] "projectdocs"              "projectfinancialtype"     "projectstatusdisplay"    
[34] "regionname"               "sector"                   "sector1"                 
[37] "sector2"                  "sector3"                  "sector4"                 
[40] "sector_namecode"          "sectorcode"               "source"                  
[43] "status"                   "supplementprojectflg"     "theme1"                  
[46] "theme_namecode"           "themecode"                "totalamt"                
[49] "totalcommamt"             "url"
```